# Counting many-to-many relationships with SQL

Tags: sql

I have Table 1, with two columns as my input and need to get to table 2 with three columns as my output using SQL. The dataset has a large number of rows.  How can I use SQL to obtain a count of all the E-A pairs in table 1 , normalized by their corresponding number of E's. Each E-A pair is one row. See Table 1 for the input and Table 2 for the desired output. Thank you very much for your help !

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, ...?

Comment: Sample data and results are better provided as tabular text so one can play around with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select
    e,
    a,
    count(*) occurences,
    1.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by e) frequency
from mytable
group by e, a
```

This puts `a` and `e` in two different columns; you can use `concat()` or the-like if you want them in one column.

Comment: Hi Gordon - thank you very much for your prompt response. It works !